# Multiple profiles using the same history/bookmarks etc.?

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile

Sometimes I need to use Firefox with a lot of different settings (like turn off several addons and change some settings to get a lower bandwidth usage).

I have the idea of having multiple profiles for that. So far, so good. But what if I want the profiles to share the history, bookmarks, open sessions/tabs, saved passwords, input field history and so on - everything except addons and config?

My actual idea is to copy the existing profile and symlink some files to the "main" profile.

Do you have a better idea to do that? Firefox Sync isn't an acceptable solution since it doesn't synchronize open tabs (it says it does, but it rather saves the open tabs as bookmarks). If symlinking is the only solution, which files do I have to symlink?

The question is moved here from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312064/firefox-multiple-profiles-using-the-same-history-bookmarks-etc

Comment: That question could be closed at SO in my opinion (it's a better fit here). symlinking or hardlinking *might work*, but Firefox (as most programs) aren't wired to read hardlinks. As long as you don't access more than one profile at a time you shouldn't have problems. And I'm saying this ***if*** Firefox doesn't store any located info on it's files. [This](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Files_and_folders_in_the_profile) is the reference for the profile files', choose those that are relevant to you.